# Google script listing folders, subfolders and files

Tags: directory, google-drive-api

I have a google script, listing me FolderName, FolderID, Filename and FileID of a Google Drive Folder including subfolders.
However, in the first row I would need the complete Full Path to the file instead only the foldername

eg a file named abc.pdf is in the folder /documents/files/new/abc.pdf

My script is showing me the foldername ***new*** instead the full folder path ***/documents/files/new/***

```
`function listFolderContents() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.appendRow(["Foldername","FolderID","Filename","FileID"]);

  var topFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID_HERE');
  var foldername = topFolderID.getName();

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();                  
  traverseFolder(folder, sheet);

  sortByFoldername();
};

function traverseFolder(folder, sheet) { 
  listFilesInFolder(folder, sheet);  
  var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    traverseFolder(subFolders.next(), sheet);
  }
}

function listFilesInFolder(folder, sheet) {
  var folderID = folder.getId();
  var foldername = folder.getName();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();  
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    var file = contents.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    var fileID = file.getId();
    sheet.appendRow( [foldername,folderID,filename,fileID] );     
  } 
}

function sortByFoldername(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D");
  range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);
  }`
```

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp

Comment: Could be... but I have no idea how to use it :(

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

I finally did it!!!
This script is working as intended and will create a List with FolderName, FolderID, Filename and FileID of all Folders and Files included in a Google Drive Fiolder:

```
    var folderId = 'FOLDERIDGOESHERE'; //Replace the folder id with the folder id of the parent folder in the Google Drive, where you would like to start sorting through the drive. 


// Main function 1: List all folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listFolders(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, false);
};

// Main function 2: List all files & folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listAll(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// =================
// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    // Get folder by id
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    // Initialise the sheet
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Folder ID", "FileName"]);

    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

  // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    // Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());
    data = [ 
      parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getId()


    ];
    // Write
    sheet.appendRow(data);

    // List files inside the folder
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      // Logger.log("File Name: " + childFile.getName());
      data = [ 
        parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
        childFolder.getId(),
        childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getId()

      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }

    // Recursive call of the subfolder
    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);  
  }
};
```